# custom php function to call in header

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, header

I have a Wordpress website. I am asking for help as I am not good with codes, but know a bit about the flow of functions and all.

I want to add a new PHP function that will be defined in a separate file. The function to be defined is required to serve a 728x90 banner ad on top of the header area of the site (so I guess the php function will also have CSS styling to align the ad in the center). I don't know what I am saying will be possible the way I am saying.

Alternatively, there might be a way to call a js function defined in separate file, then called in the php header to serve the banner (again center-aligned).

I am seeking help here as Stackoverflow also helped me solve problems previously.

Is there anyone who can help me get this thing done?

Comment: @aguyfromhere I actually don't what a handler is. As I said I am no good in coding.

Comment: @aguyfromhere Can't say anything as I don't know what exactly handlers are. I only want a banner that will display on top of the page center aligned. I want it done using either javascript or php. Have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @aguyfromhere, well the banner will be served by a javascript/html code from an ad network/affiliate program. So let me know the code to place it at the desired area. It can use it in any way, I just want to get it done. As the website is on wordpress, I was thinking that using function will be better as after I update my theme to new edition in future I don't have to do much of the changes to the new header code, it'll be done by just calling the function defined in a separate file.

Comment: @aguyfromhere say the code is in js. how to center-align it? I tried doing it using the '<center>' tags but is not working.

Comment: @aguyfromhere You want me to paste the content of the header php file here? It has a long code. It won't fit in here. I'm adding a snippet below.

Comment: `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="header">
 <div class="top-bg"></div> //function call will be here...
    <div class="layout-978">
         <?php 
          // Funcition to show the header logo, site title and site description`

Comment: Here is the code: `<!--START MERCHANT: affiliatewindow.com.-->           <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.awin1.com/cawshow.php?s=xxxxx&v=xxxx&q=xxxxx&r=xxxx"></script><noscript><iframe src="http://www.awin1.com/cawshow.php?s=305726&v=2106&q=144245&r=137264&iframe=1&target=blank" width=468 height=60 frameborder=0 border=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></iframe></noscript>       <!--START MERCHANT: affiliatewindow.com.-->`

Comment: @aguyfromhere And if the width of banner is 768px then width to this code will also need to be changed to 768px. Right? And where ad.php file need to be saved? Same folder as of header file?

Comment: @aguyfromhere I guess I am doing it in a wrong way. Have a look at the above snippet in which there is a //comment "function call will be here...". I want to call the file ad.php there. How to do it?

Comment: @aguyfromhere I got confused! I am calling file using require_once. Haven't defined any function under ad.php

Comment: Nope! Check the content of ad.php `<?php 

<div style="width:468px; margin: 0 auto">

<!--START MERCHANT: affiliatewindow.com.-->           <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.awin1.com/cawshow.php?s=xxxx&v=xxxx&q=xxxx&r=xxxx"></script><noscript><iframe src="http://www.awin1.com/cawshow.php?s=xxxxv=xxxx&q=xxxxx&r=xxxx&iframe=1&target=blank" width=468 height=60 frameborder=0 border=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></iframe></noscript>       <!--START MERCHANT: affiliatewindow.com.-->

</div>

?>`

Comment: @aguyfromhere hey, its working. The above ad script was one of the expired ones. I replaced it with the new one and its working perfectly. Its right what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your PHP handler written in a separate file call it using `require_once` like this:

```
<?php
require_once('myfile.php');

// Wordpress Stuff
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess PHP have no relation with CSS/styling, you can do it with Javascript.

[like this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) or [using JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: I guess styling can be done in a php script under the div tags. Isn't it?